# How to supress arithmetric operators in a formula in R

Tags: r, formula, infix-operator

I'm attempting to define an infix function %~% that takes a character on the left and an expression on the right and returns a concatenated formula object. So what I want `"y" %~% x + z` to return `y ~ x + z`.

However, my function (below) fails to use the `+` as a symbolic formula operator, and instead defaults to an arithmetic operator. Clearly, the `~` infix function acheives this, but it's a primitive function, so I (think I) can't go swipe the code, and I don't know how to incorporate it into the function definition to acheive my desired results.

```
`%~%` <- function(x, y) {

y <- deparse(substitute(y))
formula(paste(x, "~", y) 

}
```

A solution is to use the `~` operator when calling the function:

`"y" %~%~ x + z`

but I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent the evaluation of `+` as an arithmetic operator in the function definition so that I can simply use `%~%`.

Answer (score 1):

The order or operator precedence is fixed in R, and a little experimentation (or checking of the `?Syntax` help page) shows that the special operators bind tighter than the `+` and `-` operators:

```
`%~%` = function(left,right){
    cat("left: ",as.character(substitute(left)), "  right: ", as.character(substitute(right)),'\n')
    return(100)
}
```

which yields:

```
> 2 %~% 1 + 3
left:  2   right:  1 
[1] 103
> 2 %~% (1 + 3)
left:  2   right:  ( 1 + 3 
[1] 100
```

or maybe a bit more clearly:

```
zz <- function(x){
    x <- substitute(x)
    cat(sprintf("%s [%s] %s\n",
                             as.character(deparse(x[[2]])),
                             as.character(deparse(x[[1]])),
                             as.character(deparse(x[[3]]))))}
```

which yields:

```
> zz(1 + 2)
1 [+] 2
> zz(1 + 2:3)
1 [+] 2:3
> zz(1 + 2%foo%3)
1 [+] 2 %foo% 3
> zz(2%foo%3+1)
2 %foo% 3 [+] 1
```

Note also that formula's capture the environment in which they are created, so creating a formula in a helper function may have some unexpected and difficult to debug consequences if you don't take care to bind the correct environment to your formula object.